# WTForms/Flask-WTF class attributes vs instance attributes

Tags: python, flask-wtforms, metaclass

I'm now trying to use Flask-WTF (powered by WTForms) to render my frontend forms submission.

However, there is a limitation that all the fields in a `Form` object are class-level attributes, namely all instances of the class share the same fields.

When I tried to add multiple form instances and render them on the same page, it just doesn't work because the `__init__` function in a `Form` subclass doesn't work, you cannot add fields or modify fields in the `__init__` function, and all the instances are sort of "synchronized" after I clicked the submit button.

I'm essentially trying to make a single submit button that submits several forms, while this built-in functionality of `Form` object hinders the process. I'm now trying to modify the `BaseForm` class which is inherited by `Form`, and see if I can dig out something to work :(

I believe this has something to do with the `Metaclass` in WTForms, if anyone has encountered this problem please save me, and many thanks...

Comment: It's a design decision. A single type of form is represented by a class, you need different classes for forms with different fields. You can however if that is really needed produce classes on the fly in python

Comment: If they are all instances of the same form, consider passing different `prefix` values to the `__init__`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yeah I have done that but it turns out to be messy tho, that could be a workaround, thank you...